# BigQuery ML - Syntax error: Unclosed comment. When creating model

Tags: google-bigquery

I have encountered an issue. I want to create a model from a query involving 4 different tables. 
However I am presented with the following error: Syntax error - Unclosed comment

Code in standard SQL:

```
CREATE MODEL `project.test1`
Options
(model_type='logistic_reg', labels = ['days_between_dates']) AS

WITH all_dates AS (SELECT ID, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(date)))
, info AS (SELECT ID, info)
, first_date AS (SELECT ID, date)
, second_date AS(SELECT ID, date)

SELECT * , DATE_DIFF(first_date.date, second_date.date) AS days_between_dates
FROM all_dates 
JOIN first_date USING (ID)
JOIN second_date USING (ID)
LEFT JOIN info USING (ID)
WHERE days_between_dates > 1
```

The code works as intended and is able to run without the addition of CREATE MODEL statement (first three lines of code).

Any help would be appreciated to point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved with the following code:

```
CREATE MODEL `project.test1`
Options
(model_type='logistic_reg', labels = ['days_between_dates']) AS

SELECT * , DATE_DIFF(first_date.date, second_date.date) AS days_between_dates
FROM (SELECT ID, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(date)))
JOIN (SELECT ID, date) first_date USING (ID)
JOIN (SELECT ID, date) second_date USING (ID)
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, info) USING (ID)
WHERE days_between_dates > 1
```

However "Training is not supported for datatype ARRAY< STRUCT..."